# How shall I say "star" and "unstar" (as in Github) in Russian?

Tags: выбор-слова

Как сказать "star" и "unstar" (типа как отметить репозиторий звёздочной на GitHub'е или снять такую отметку) кратко и ясно? Желательно литературно, без "лайкнуть" и т.д.

How to say "star" and "unstar" (as if you marking a repository with star on Github or removing such mark) shortly and clearly? Advisably not slangish like "to put a like" and so on...

Comment: Снять звизду? Добавить звизду? Duh!

Comment: You cannot start a question with "How to say". It is incorrect.

Comment: Tried to fix "How to say"; Seems like there is no one-word equivalent for "unstar"...

Comment: The problem with translating such English word pairs is that Russian lacks two English features: almost any noun can serve as verb and almost any verb allows adding "un-" prefix.

Comment: Easy: звездануть и отзвездануть. :)  Или раззвездануть. :)

Comment: @Dima Если серьезно заниматься словотворчеством, то _to star_ — это, очевидно, _позвездить_. С _to unstar_ сложнее — ни приставка _раз-_, ни _от-_ сами по себе вообще-то не имеют смысла отмены действия.

Comment: @Dima Я вовсе не припомню в русском языке приставки, сколько-нибудь соответствующей английской _un-_. _Unload_ — _разгрузить_,  _undo_ — _отменить_ и тому подобные аналогии ложны. _Раз-_ здесь имеет значение раз’единения (такое же как в _разобрать_), _от-_ — то же, что в словах _ответить_, _отказать_.

Comment: @Dima Но если таки задаться целью придумать глагол со значением «снять звезду», то это будет _обеззвездить_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to previous answers:

**star** — "проголосовать", "проголосовать «за»", "отдать свой голос" (up-vote)
**unstar** — "проголосовать «против»", "снять свой голос" (down-vote)

or
**star/unstar** — "поставить(дать, отдать) звезду"/"снять(убрать, забрать) звезду"

or
**star/unstar** — "плюсануть"/"минусануть" (slang, to click on 'plus' or 'minus')

Answer (score 4):

Если брать в качестве примера тот же самый GitHub, то имеет смысл рассмотреть практическую значимость "проставления звезд": люди используют их для того, чтобы:
1. Выразить свое положительное отношение к проекту.
2. Иметь возможность быстрого доступа к проектам, интересующим пользователя.
Исходя из этих значений можно формулировать краткие аналоги для русского языка, при этом совершенно не обязательно использовать глаголы. Вот несколько подходящих вариантов:
**Интересно / Не интересно**
**Поддержать / Не поддерживать**
**Отметить / Снять отметку** (предложено ovgolovin)
**В избранное / Удалить из избранного**
**Нравится / Не нравится**
**Важно / Не важно**

Если немного отвлечься от концепции GitHub, в котором функция отслеживания является отдельной возможностью, то в каких-то случаях могут подойти слова **Отслеживать/Не отслеживать**. В любом случае, при переводе данной функциональности нужно рассматривать, в чем заключается смысл данной функции в конкретном сервисе/приложении/и т.д.

Comment: Роман, заметьте, что автор вопроса прежде всего интересуется как обозначить *действие*

Comment: @shabunc увы, не замечаю, сколько ни перечитываю вопрос. Кроме того, предложенные мной варианты в любом случае могут быть полезны автору в решении его задачи.

Answer (score 3):

`star` I would tranlate as `Выделить` или `Отметить`.

`unstar` I would translate as `Снять выделение` или `Снять отметку`.

I don't see any more eloquent variants as loquacious `Снять выделение` or `Снять отметку`.

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward translation will be: "отметить звёздочкой" to indicate "starring" action. This is 100% understandable but nevertheless sounds quite unnatural to native. Moreover there's no such straightforward equivalent for the opposite action - phrase "разометить звёзочкой" is incorrect.

Saying "добавить звёздочку" / "убрать звёздочку" (to add/to remove a star) is acceptable, but there's a subtle inconsistency between the action itself and the actions' description. Adding a star to some entity and starring it are a slightly different things.

But, yet there is no exact (especially "not slang") equivalent of "star"/"unstar" pair, words "залайкать"/"отлайкать" are very common in modern Russian web slang. Since those terms are very close in almost all cases, I'd recommend nervertheless this translation. I hardly believe you'll find anything more relevant.