# What's the verb for "email" in Russian?

Tags: перевод, одним-словом, информатика

How do you say "email" (as a verb) in a single word?

Comment: I would say "выслать на почту" or simply "выслать" if the context of doing so via e-mail is clear. If it isn't clear then I would say this in full "выслать на электронную почту". Synonyms are "отправить, отослать, послать".

Comment: Sometimes people use the word "намылить" to express "to email" in Russian. That is from jargon adoptation of transliteration of "email" - "мыло". http://slovoborg.su/definition/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: The search for one-word verb "email" translation is similar to discussion for star/unstar: http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2450/how-shall-i-say-star-and-unstar-as-in-github-in-russian (see comments to the question).

Comment: There is no single word that would unequivocally and unconfusingly state "to email", unfortunately. "Отправить/послать/выслать по имэйлу" would be the closest equivalent, basically means "send by/using e-mail"

Comment: Послать / отправить (на мыло).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Отправить, Послать(Отослать), Написать.
Особенной дифференциации между обычной почтой и электронной почтой не наблюдается.
Оба варианта имеют свой устойчивый контекст, который слабо пересекается между собой. Пожалуй, отправка письма обычной почтой, требует уточнений, а не отправка мыла: *Я отправил тебе письмо почтой.* *Я отправил заказное письмо.*
Хотя последнее возможно субьективное утверждение.

*Написать* тоже скорее всего потребует уточнений, с незнакомыми(мало знакомыми) с вашим вкусом реципиентами - напишите в контакт, напишите в icq, напишите в ирц, напишите на почту(подразумевается электронная почта без вариантов))

*Отправить* - оттенок смысла больше в упоре на действие
Отправил сообщение (IM or whatever) , Отправил почту (как вариант), Отправил письмо, Отпавил файл, Отправил архив, Отправил пачку печенья (тут уже вопрос насколько печеньки были реальны)), Отправил посылку (тут несколько вариантов, но скорее всего не электронные)

*Отослал, Послал, Заслал* - эти, пожалуй, наиболее зависимые от контекста. Устойчивые, достаточно определенные варианты, для offline: *Послал посылку. Послал открытку.*

Comment: translate I can't, if I could I probably did that already) Yes commas is my pain, but looks like i managed to place more then a half of them. Ok let it be maybe it will get some inspiration for others. Hmm but yes I see the point, mm did't thinked that about before writing, feel free to delete.

Comment: However it is quite useful, therefore +1

Comment: 50 reps are yours.

Comment: @nicael be my guest any time ))

Answer (score 6):

#Update 2023#

I must admit that my answer didn’t age well. I don’t see the jargon used anymore. At this moment, there doesn’t seem to be a single-word verb for “email” in Russian. I only see the literal expression “send an email”, i.e. informally «пошли имейл» or more formally, «отправьте электронной почтой».

#Original#

I can suggest a jargon word, "намыльте," for "email" as a verb. Here's [an example of its usage](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/relcom.games/cDIA35wvAlo):

> Намыльте коды для Duke. Plssss

It's from the jargon word "мыло" for email. The verb isn't used as much as the noun, though. It's a stretch to say that the word "мыло" in Russian sounds like "email," frankly, but it's probably the Russian word that sounds the least dissimilar.

[Google used](http://www.sostav.ru/news/2008/02/06/r3vopr/) the jargon word in its 2008 [Gmail promotion](http://www.gbs.com.ua/ru/company/articles/253.html):

> "Мыло Gmail" - интерактивная акция для студентов, направленная на продвижение почтового ящика Gmail, путем использования российской сленговой ассоциации email и мыла.

> Gmail soap - interactive promotion for students, aimed at promotion of Gmail, by way of using Russian slang word "мыло" (a soap) for "email."

[image: Cake of soap, with "Gmail" stamped on it. The packet reads "Gmail - самое чистое мыло"]

Comment: This one is never used. It will cause confusion in 99% cases.

Comment: @Dvole, "never" is a strong word. Here's a few examples: [2007](http://forums.drom.ru/car-audio/t1150933333.html), [1999](http://www.germcar.ru/forum11/topic838601/),[2002](http://taxhelp.ru/forum/3--/144900----.html),[2013](http://conf.7ya.ru/fulltext-thread.aspx?cnf=BuyTalk&trd=237068), [etc](http://www.autofx.ru/otvet/show.pl?ID=637011). Google the word and you'll see many more examples of usage.

Comment: @Aksakal just sharing my experience as native speaker, never heard anyone say this, maybe in some geek-related magazines like 10 years ago, but it was unpopular even then

Comment: I agree with Dvole. I've never heard it to be used that way. And saying it that way will most likely cause confusion. I would be confused myself if I didn't know it had anything to do with mail.

Comment: I hear it all the time; but I wouldn't use it in a conversation with my Aunt Avdotya. Then again, I wouldn't use "smiley" with Aunt Avdotya either, until she heard it in Verka Serduchka's song.

Answer (score 5):

Two words: послать and отправить, almost the same.

Comment: also отослать and выслать http://enc-dic.com/synonym/Otpravit-272022.html

Comment: @nicael both verbs mean "send" that is too general to mean "email" without additional context.

Answer (score 4):

Послать.

*Has he **emailed** you that list of addresses yet?* Он тебе **послал** список адресов?

Comment: "Послать" is rather "mail" than "email". But, anyway, good alternative.

Comment: I think this is context-related word. If you use this word in SMS you'll likely get the list of addresses in SMS, not by email.

Comment: Yes, "послать" is context-related, it's actually just verb "send". There is no special verbs for sending an sms (to text) or sending an email (to email). So we either use common verbs like "послать", "скинуть", "написать" or jargonism "намылить". We don't even have a specific noun for email...

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use slang, then "послать по электронной почте".

Comment: "одним-словом"?

Comment: @nicael it can be reduced to: "Послать по почте" or "Послать", but only in the context

Comment: @w.hrybok: "отправить письмо" is almost universally understood as "send e-mail". Dead-tree mail could be clarifyed explicitly as "бумажная почта".

Answer (score 2):

I use **отправить**:
Email me those logs please - отправьте мне те логи, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Имейлить, имейльнуть - скоро во всех словарях России :-D

Add: Никогда раньше не встречал этих слов и вряд ли их кто-то использует на практике.
Но думаю, что их можно использовать и большинство людей поймет их значение, даже услышав впервые в жизни.

Comment: "Имейлить"? Really? Then, +1.

Comment: "скоро во всех словарях России" - откуда информация?

Comment: @Highstaker, это шутка, там же смайлик

Comment: @nicael, in Lingvo: "email - электронное письмо; имейл разг.", then for example: спор - спорить, сверло - сверлить => имейл - имейлить :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such possibility.

> Отправить эл. почту

is the best for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a button in web form - "**Пишите**" or "**Пишите нам**".
In other cases (in correspondence, for example) - "**Пришлите**", "**отправьте**", "**вышлите**", but it context-dependent.